# Using laptop keyboard shuts down computer

Tags: drivers, nvidia, keyboard, asus, amd-processor

I've just bought a new laptop from Asus: Rog Strix Scar G17 G733QS and I tried installing Ubuntu 20.04 on it.

The problem is that every time I press any key on the laptop keyboard, the shut-down dialog/pop-up appears and if I forget about this and mistakenly press multiple keys, the laptop shuts down.

It seems that I can use Ubuntu just fine with an USB keyboard, but this is clearly not okay.

Do you have any idea about what I could do?

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you run Ubuntu from a live USB?

Comment: No, during installation it worked ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the comment here, first updating your kernal to >= 5.11.x, and then following the steps, then installing NVIDIA drivers.

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-mate-20-04-with-rtx-3070-on-ryzen-5900-black-screen-after-boot/167681/30

Comment: I installed ubuntu 21 , upgraded the kernel to 5.11.18 , installed nvidia drivers 460 . but keyboard issue remains .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 21.04. You can fix the problem by installing the latest release candidate kernel 5.13 rc 5.

A comprehensive tutorial for installing a kernel manually can be found here:
https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/

The kernel that solved my problem can be found here:
[https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.13-rc5/amd64/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.13-rc5/amd64/)

Enjoy your new laptop :-)

Comment: Did you resolve the issue on Ubunutu 20.04 or 21.04 ?

Comment: I fixed ist on Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the keyboard then open a terminal and try

```
sudo apt update
```

followed by

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

(in normal session, not live session)